# Running two exe files in one c# project

Tags: c#, console, exe

---

I'm trying to write a program which executes 2 different .exe files and outputs their results to a text file. When I execute them separately, they work fine, but when I try to execute them both, the second process doesn't run. Can anyone help?

Here is the code. Player1.exe and Player2.exe are console applications returning 0 or 1.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process process1 = new Process();
        process1.StartInfo.FileName = "C:/Programming/Tournament/Player1.exe";
        process1.StartInfo.Arguments = "";
        process1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process1.Start();
        var result1 = process1.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        process1.Close();

        Process process2 = new Process();
        process2.StartInfo.FileName = "C:/Programming/Tournament/Player2.exe";
        process2.StartInfo.Arguments = "";
        process2.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process2.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process2.Start();
        string result2 = process2.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd().ToString();
        process2.Close();

        string resultsPath = "C:/Programming/Tournament/Results/Player1vsPlayer2.txt";
        if (!File.Exists(resultsPath))
        {
            StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(resultsPath);
            sw.WriteLine("Player1 " + "Player2");
            sw.WriteLine(result1 + " " + result2);
            sw.Flush();
        }


    }
```

Comment: Your code already works that way, ReadToEnd() doesn't complete until the process quits.  Hard to guess why you are asking this question.

Comment: The program doesn't even reach to process2. I tested that by putting a breakpoint.

Comment: Define them on threads, and start those

Answer (score 0):

**1.**

you wrote in a comment: "The program doesn't even reach to process2. I tested that by putting a breakpoint."

`process1.Start()` may be throwing an exception.  Rather than setting a breakpoint at process2, step through the lines and find the exception.  Or better yet, add a try/catch block and report an error.

**2.**

Another possibility is that `ReadToEnd` is not behaving as expected.  You can `Peek` and see if there is more data to read by looping like this:

```
var result1 = new StringBuilder()
while (process1.StandardOutput.Peek() > -1)
{
   result1.Append(process1.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
}
```

**3.**

If these processes don't immediately provide data and end, then you need to get them both started before you begin waiting on their StandardOutput.  Call `Start()` on each process before doing the reads.

Comment: Could be. Surprised VS isn't throwing a fit you're not escaping your string. Try "C://Programming//Tournament//Player2.exe";

Comment: @scnrio backslashes need to be doubled or start the literal with ampersand.  Forward slashes appear to work fine.

Comment: I think if there were problems the process1 won't run separately. When I make comment the process2 part, process1 works fine.

Comment: ahh yea my bad. Just looked funny at first, but you're right. I'll see if I can come up with a solution for you

Comment: @Lusine good.  Was the problem 1, 2, or 3?  Accept the answer when you get a chance.  Everyone likes Fake Internet Points ;)

Comment: The problem was 3rd one :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know too much about using process, but I use this approach when I need separate things to run at once. I didn't pull in the bottom portion of your project, but check this out to see if it helps in any way.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process process1 = new Process();
        process1.StartInfo.FileName = "C:/Programming/Tournament/Player1.exe";
        process1.StartInfo.Arguments = "";
        process1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        Process process2 = new Process();
        process2.StartInfo.FileName = "C:/Programming/Tournament/Player2.exe";
        process2.StartInfo.Arguments = "";
        process2.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process2.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;


        Thread T1 = new Thread(delegate() {
            doProcess(process1);
        });

        Thread T2 = new Thread(delegate() {
            doProcess(process2);
        });

        T1.Start();
        T2.Start();
    }

    public static void doProcess(Process myProcess)
    {
        myProcess.Start();
        var result1 = myProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        myProcess.Close();
    }
}
```